# code guards fail

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors, include-guards, multiple-definition-error

Take this files:

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

char EL[] = "el";
#endif
```

a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"
```

b.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "a.h"

#endif
```

b.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
```

main.cpp

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a.h"

int main() { }
```

This is only an example, but I've really this problem:

```
g++ -c a.cpp
g++ -c b.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o a.o b.o


a.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `EL'
main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
b.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `EL'
main.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

why and how to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't my include guards preventing recursive inclusion and multiple symbol definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Include guards don't protect you against *defining* an object multiple times if you include the definition in multiple translation units!

As a solution, never *define* things in headers, but only *declare* them:

```
// header
extern char EL[2];

// TU
#include "header.h"
char EL[2] = "el";

// Other consumer
#include "header.h";
// can now use EL
```

(There are exceptions, of course; e.g. class definitions are fine (but class member function definitions are not (but inlined ones are)) -- beware.)

---

I should add that alternatively you can say `static` in your header file to make the definition private to each TU:

```
// header
static char EL[] = "EL";  // every TU gets a copy
```

(In C++0x you cannot use objects of static linkage as template parameters, though.)

Comment: I need to define it in header because I need to specialize a template with a literal string. Like: `typedef SimpleParticleDecorator<11, EL, true, false> ElectronDecorator;`

Comment: Post that as a separate question, we'll take a look.

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804029/code-guards-fail-and-template-from-string-literal