# C++ class not within scope

Tags: c++, c++builder

I have a class called Video and is defined as the following:

```
class Video
{
public:
    Video() { }
    ~Video()
    {

    }

    unsigned int m_max_ad_duration;
    unsigned int m_max_skippable_duration;
    unsigned int m_start_delay;
    unsigned short int m_inventory_type;
    unsigned short int m_skippable_Request;
};
```

If i have the above in a fresh file called Video.h the build works fine, however when i declare the above in an existing file containing a number of classes the build fails with errors such as

```
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:56: error: ‘Video’ was not declared in this scope
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:62: error: template argument 2 is invalid
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:64: error: template argument 2 is invalid
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:64: error: template argument 5 is invalid
../../include/CampaignCache.h:33:89: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
../../include/CampaignCache.h:97:51: error: ‘Video’ has not been declared
make[2]: *** [BaseOpenRTBBidRequest.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/asif/RTB3.0trunk/trunk/3.0/src/bidder/ssp/OpenRTB'
make[1]: *** [OpenRTB] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/asif/RTB3.0trunk/trunk/3.0/src/bidder'
make: *** [compile] Error 2
```

Ideally i would like the Video class within the file with subclasses, can someone please  explain why one causes a build error and the other doesn't?

Comment: please format your code properly.

Comment: Looks like a circular include issue.

Comment: If the problem is due to circular inclusion and you are wondering why include guards do not help (provided you used them at all), [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol) might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: provide a complete small example

Comment: It's either a circular include problem, or you declared `Video` after line 97 of `CampaignCache.h`. You can't use it before you've declared it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simply put the video class in an independent file and all started to work fine