# Proper use of header in C++

Tags: c++, header-files

I am playing around with multiple files in C++, and I have come of with the following example with does not compile:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    extern double var;
    var = 5;
    cout << var << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

fct.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "const.hpp"

using namespace std;

void func()
{
    extern double var;
    cout << var << endl;

}
```

const.hpp

```
#ifndef CONST_H
#define CONST_H

double var;

#endif
```

My program does not compile, because apparently there is a multi-definition of var. Am I correct to assume that, based on this example, a header file is *not* intended to be used for declaring variables as in my example above?

Instead, the correct procedure is to declare all variables in a .cpp file and use a header to tell each (relevant) translation unit that the .cpp file contains an external (*extern*) variable?

EDIT: Is it correct that an exeption to my rule above is when dealing with constant variables (const), which should be defined in a header?

Comment: It does compile, it does not link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that, based on this example, a header file is not intended to be used for declaring variables as in my example above?

A header file is intended for declaring variables, but your header file *defines* a global variable with external linkage, and it is imported multiple times. The linker then reasonably complains about multiply defined symbols.

> Instead, the correct procedure is to declare all variables in a .cpp file and use a header to tell each (relevant) translation unit that the .cpp file contains an external (extern) variable?

Yes, except that you would not be *declaring* the global variables in that `.cpp` file, but rather providing a *definition* for them.

`const.hpp`

```
    #ifndef CONST_H
    #define CONST_H

    // ...

    extern double var;
//  ^^^^^^

    #endif
```

`globals.cpp` (could be any other `.cpp` file, as long as it is *only one*)

```
    // ...

    double var;
```

Also, if you are wondering about the reason why your include guards won't protect you in this case, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol/14909999#14909999) may help you .

> Is it correct that an exception to my rule above is when dealing with constant variables (const), which should be defined in a header?

In a sense, yes. Global variables qualified as `const` have *internal linkage* by default, which means that each translation unit will receive a *private* copy of that variable. So even when the variable's definition is included by multiple translation unit, the linker will not complain about multiply defined symbols.

Answer (score 4):

`double var;` is a definition - including that header in multiple files will violate the one definition rule. If you want a global (think twice) you'll have to **declare** it in the header - `extern double var;` and move the definition to a single implementation file.

Comment: Or even better: stop using global variables. They'll only bring you pain and despair.