# Use global variable declared in header by more C++ files

Tags: c++, variables, dll, export, global

I am trying to create a dynamic library from various .cpp files sharing the same .h. It's something like this:

```
// mylib1.cpp
namespace mylib {
    namespace part1 {
        void init() {
            part1::commonvar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
// mylib2.cpp
namespace mylib {
    namespace part2 {
        void check() {
            if (part1::commonvar == true) {
                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the common header

```
// mylib.h
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif
    namespace mylib {
        namespace part1 {
            bool commonvar = false;
            void init();
        }
        namespace part2 {
            void check();
        }
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

I am using GCC (MingW) to compile and link this into a single DLL like this:

```
g++ -Wall -s -O2 -c mylib1.cpp -o mylib1.o
g++ -Wall -s -O2 -c mylib2.cpp -o mylib2.o
g++ -Wall -s -O2 -shared -o MyLib.dll -Wl,--out-implib=lib/libMyLib.dll.a mylib1.o mylib2.o
```

So, my problem is that when I do all this I get multiple definition error for that variable, when trying to link those two objects. So, I wonder if there's a workaround to make *commonvar* be common for both namespaces, but not duplicated in both object files. I can make it a member of the namespace "*mylib*", if necessary, and I can use pre-processor commands, too.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-`const` global variables have external linkage. You are importing the same *definition* of the `commonvar` global variables into several translation units, and the linker will eventually complain that you defined that symbol more than once, violating the One Definition Rule.

You should use the `extern` keyword to turn the definition of your global variable into a `declaration`, and define the global variable in just *one* `.cpp` file:

**MyLib.h**

```
namespace mylib {
    namespace part1 {
        extern bool commonvar;
    //  ^^^^^^
        void init();
    }
    namespace part2 {
        void check();
    }
}
```

**MyLib.cpp** (or any other `.cpp` file, as long as it is *only one*)

```
namespace mylib {
    namespace part1 {
        bool commonvar;
    }
}
```

If you are wondering why your include guards (in case you are using them) are not preventing multiple definitions of the same symbol in different translation units, [**see this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol)

Comment: I will try this. I understand what is going on under the hood, I just didn't know how to make it be understood as an exter/exported element.

Comment: Works like charm. Initialization of that variable can be made in the cpp or the header? Thanks

Comment: @ali: In the `.cpp`. What you have in the header is just a *declaration*.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following

```
  bool* init(){
      static bool commonvar = false;
      return &commonvar;     
  }
```

Comment: ...as a last solution I will create a function to return that

Comment: because compiler compiles each source file seperately will have the same symbol in multiple object files , finally linking will generate linker error. extern keyword can be used to avoid that.