# template conversion operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I want to overload conversion operator for two templates.

A.h

```
#pragma once

#include <B.h>

template <typename T> class A
{
operator B<T>() const;
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

#include <A.h>

template <typename T> class B
{
operator A<T>() const;
}
```

I got error

```
error C2833: 'operator A' is not a recognized operator or type see
reference to class template instantiation 'B<T>' being compiled
```

Although it works if conversion operator is overloaded only in one template.

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol) can help (`#pragma once` basically works as an include guard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency problem.  You need to have a forward declaration, such as:

A.h:

```
#pragma once

template <class T> class B;

template <class T> class A {
   operator B<T>() const;
};

#include "B.h"

template <class T>
A<T>::operator B<T>() const {
   foo();
}
```

B.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"

template <class T>
class B {
   operator A<T>() const {
      bar();
   }
};
```

I assume you used `#include "A.h"`.  A.h then included B.h.  When the compiler started compiling B.h, it had not yet seen a declaration for A.h, and thus the compiler did not know how to interpret `operator A<T>() const`, as it does not know that A is a type.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Somehow it just works with `template <class T> class A;` in B.h and `template <class T> class B;` in A.h without any includes. Compiler - Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Yes.  It will work - the answer I gave is for the cases where the implementation of `A<T>::operator B<T>()` cannot compile without a visible implementation of class `B<T>`.  This way both implementations are able to see the full definition of each class.  Just keep in mind that in this pattern `B<T>` may have a member of type `A<T>`, but `A<T>` may *not* have a member of type `B<T>` (but may have a member of type pointer to or reference to `B<T>`).