# C++ include files confusion

Tags: c++, header, include, forward-declaration

I'm trying to include files in my c++ program but I keep encountering the error:

`ShapeVisitor.h:9:28: error: ‘Circle’ has not been declared`

I think the problem is that the way the classes are structured, it results in a circular dependence. How do I solve this?

The class headers are below...

```
 //Circle.h
 #ifndef CIRCLE_H
 #define CIRCLE_H
 // headers, ...
 #include "Shape.h"
class Circle: public Shape { 
//class declaration 
}
#endif

//Shape.h
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H
// headers, ...
#include <iostream>

class Shape {  
//a certain method in the class declaration looks like this
virtual void accept(ShapeVisitor& v) = 0; 
//rest of class
}
#endif

//ShapeVisitor.h
#ifndef SHAPEVISITOR_H
#define SHAPEVISITOR_H
#include "Circle.h"
class ShapeVisitor {
//a method in the class looks like this:
virtual void visitCircle(Circle *s) = 0;
//rest of class
}
#endif
```

As you can see, circle includes shape, which includes shapevisitor, which again, includes circle.

Any ideas?

Comment: As you can see... I must be blind, I don't see it. What I see is no includes, so the Cyrcle is undeclared.

Comment: Your class definitions need semicolons.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol) could help figuring out what's going on in detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ShapeVisitor.h does not need to include Circle.h, a forward declaration `class Circle;` will do. Function declarations do not require the full definitions of their argument and return types (not even if the return/arguments are by value!). Only the function's implementation file (in your case: ShapeVisitor.cpp) would need to include Circle.h.

This [ancient](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/007.htm) (but still very true!) column by Herb Sutter is a nice reference.

Comment: @artlessnoise thanks for elaborating what a forward declaration is, added. But note that even if the function signature would have been `void visitCircle(Circle s)`, the header would not have been necessary!

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks for the explaination! I'm assuming then, in my Shape class, I only need a forward declaration of "ShapeVisitor" as well then?

Comment: @docaholic yes correct, but note that Circle.h does need to include Shape.h because a derived class needs the base class definition in order to be defined itself.

Comment: Sorry, it is a while since I programmed in C++.  Derivation or composition.

Comment: Thanks rhalbersma, that really made a lot more sense. I'd upvote your answer twice if i could!

Comment: @docaholic great to have been of help.