# Weird Linker error from overloaded << operator - C++

Tags: c++, debugging, linker

I wrote a small Timer class to check my code's performance. The sourcecode can be found here http://pastebin.com/i1PX2VPN (I'll hightlight important sections later here)

Now I faced a very weird error: The code linked above is in a file Timer.hpp. I use this file in my main.cpp and it works just fine. However, I also want to use it in another source file, and then, as soon as I add a

```
  #include <Timer.hpp>
```

into the next source file, I get the following linker error:

```
  ld: duplicate symbol operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, Timer const&) in /var/folders/XZ/XZ93KWBqG0SR1aCVpTCVQE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccyaHyyU.o and /var/folders/XZ/XZ93KWBqG0SR1aCVpTCVQE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccETAaTw.o
  collect2: ld return 1 as exit status
  make: *** [debugd] Error 1
```

The function is

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) {
         return os << std::scientific << std::setw(8)  << std::setprecision(3)
                            << t.timeTotal_ << " \t " << t.timeMin_ << " \t " <<          t.timeMax_;
   }
```

Nothing too fancy... again: It works as long as it is only included in my main.cpp

Obviously this seems to be a problem with multiple definitions (?) of the operator. But I cannot understand why or how to solve it. I use include-guards to save it from being included multiple times.

I already checked whether there is another Timer class anywhere else in the C++-library I never heard of, which is obviously not the case (renaming the class doesn't change anything anyway)...

In the Timer.hpp, there is also another class defined, also with its own operator<< overloaded. I don't know whether this is important, I just think I should mention it

So... I'm looking to forward to your ideas, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should mark your function as `inline`, since it is a global function whose definition is included by more than one translation unit.

```
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Timer& t) {
//  ^^^^^^
         return os << std::scientific << std::setw(8)  << std::setprecision(3)
               << t.timeTotal_ << " \t " << t.timeMin_ << " \t " 
               << t.timeMax_;
    }
```

Alternatively, you can leave the declaration of the function in the header, and put the definition in one single `.cpp` file.

If you are wondering why include guards are not saving you from multiple symbol definitions, you may find **[this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol)** useful.

Answer (score 3):

Include guards only prevent a file from being included multiple times *in the same translation unit*. If you are including it in two different `.cpp` files that you compile seperately (which `.cpp` files usually are), you have multiple definitions.

Put it in an implementation file, leaving only a declaration in the header.

Comment: Thank you to you as well :)