# 'operator Apple' is not a recognized operator or type when including a header

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading

I'll make it short.

I have 2 classes: `Apple` and `Orange`, as the following:

`Apple.h` (`Apple.c` is blank)

```
#ifndef APPLE_H_
#define APPLE_H_

class Apple {};

#endif /* APPLE_H_ */
```

`Orange.h`:

```
#ifndef ORANGE_H_
#define ORANGE_H_

#include "Apple.h"

class Orange {
public:
    Orange();
    virtual ~Orange();
    operator Apple ();
};

#endif /* ORANGE_H_ */
```

`Orange.cpp`:

```
#include "Orange.h"

Orange::Orange() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

Orange::~Orange() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

Orange::operator Apple() {
    Apple y;
    return y;
}
```

As these, these are works great.

but when I add `#include  "Orange.h"` to `Apple.h` , I get `'operator Apple'  is not a recognized operator or type` error.

as the following:

```
#ifndef APPLE_H_
#define APPLE_H_

#include "Orange.h"

class Apple {};

#endif /* APPLE_H_ */
```

What is the problem that `#include "Orange.h"` makes?

Comment: A circular include is the problem.

Comment: Actually that code should work, `Orange.cpp` includes `Orange.h` which includes `Apple.h` which *does not* include `Orange.h` since `ORANGE_H_` is already defined, or am I mistaken?

Comment: You need to forward declare `Apple` in `Orange.h`: `class Apple;`

Comment: @filmor "but when I add #include "Orange.h" to Apple.h , I get 'operator Apple' is not a recognized operator or type error."

Comment: Seriously, I've tested the code and it compiles (for the reasons I've given in my comment before). Could you please provide a not working example? :)

Comment: This should help (the *first* question is relevant in that Q&A): [Why aren't my include guards preventing recursive inclusion and multiple symbol definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol)

Comment: @filmor read the question carefully.

Comment: @juanchopanza Read carefully and try out the code provided. Or point me to the exact part where I'm misunderstanding the question. The circular dependency stuff does not matter here as `Orange.h` is included. It is only a problem when you include `Apple.h` as only in that case `class Apple` is declared after the definition of `class Orange`.

Comment: @filmor I tried to compile it and it doesn't compile. What a surprise.

Comment: @filmor, you say: "_It is only a problem when you include `Apple.h` as only in that case `class Apple` is declared after the definition of `class Orange`_", but `Apple` is declared after `Orange` since `Apple` depends on `Orange`. So, circular dependency is matter here.

Comment: @juanchopanza I copy and pasted the code, if this doesn't compile in Visual C++ I'd consider it a bug in the preprocessor. Could you provide the output of the preprocessor?

Comment: @soon It does matter indeed, but IMHO it doesn't lead to an error in this particular case. If there where an implementation file for `class Apple` it would.

Comment: @filmor  I am using G++. I made an `Apple.cpp` file which only contains `#include Apple.h"`, and build `Orange.o` and `Apple.o`. The latter gives the error I quote in my answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza So you added a new file to the problem… `Apple.cpp` (or as it's called here `Apple.c`) is supposed to be blank.

Comment: @filmor There's no preprocessor bug.  It's simply wrong.  If `Apple.h` includes `Orange.h`, `Orange.h` will try including `Apple.h` again (but it will do nothing due to the `APPLE_H_` guard), and you end up with the `Orange` class definition that references the `Apple` type before `Apple` is declared.

Comment: @jamesdlin But only if there is `#include "Apple.h"` in any implementation file *before* `#include "Orange.h"`. In the code provided by the OP this is not the case.

Comment: @filmor Ah, I see what you mean.  Yeah, maybe there's something that the OP isn't telling us then. (Regardless, the circular `#include` is still a bad idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you now have a circular dependency: `Orange.h` depends on `Apple.h` which depends on `Orange.h` etc.

In the `Orange.h` header file it might be enough to declare the `Apple` class:

```
// Tell the compiler that there is a class named `Apple`
class Apple;

class Orange {
public:
    Orange();
    virtual ~Orange();
    operator Apple ();
};
```

Then in the `Orange.cpp` source file you include the `Apple.h` header file.

Comment: Not exactly, but I found a workaround using your tip. thanks. I'll wait for more answers - it there won't, I'll flag yours as best. thanks.