# Friend member function definition conflicts with in-class initializer

Tags: c++, class, c++11, friend

I was reading [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) recently and was trapped by the same code [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31342839/5340808) (with a little difference), but my question is different. I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but after searching around, it seems no answer could answer my question.

At the very beginning, the code worked fine when I didn't add the friend member function.

```
/* First class */
class Screen {
public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    using content_type = char;

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, content_type c)
        : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {}

    // Other inline functions are omited.

private:
    pos width = 0;
    pos height = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

/* Second class */
class Window_mgr {
public:
    using screen_index = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;

private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80, ' ')};  // Use `Screen` ctor
};
```

Then, I want to add the friend member function `clear`. I wrote two versions of code according to code near page 281 in the book. The first version uses in-class initializer to initialize the `vector` data member of `Window_mgr`, while the second version uses constructor initializer list.

The first version (**error**) just like what the book wrote:

> Making a member function a friend requires careful structuring of our programs
>   to accommodate interdependencies among the declarations and definitions. In this example, we must order our program as follows:
>
> - First, define the `Window_mgr` class, which declares, but cannot define `clear`. `Screen` must be declared before `clear` can use the members of `Screen`.
> - Next, define class `Screen`, including a friend declaration for `clear`.
> - Finally, define `clear`, which can now refer to the members in `Screen`.

```
/* Part 1, usually Window_mgr.h */
class Screen;

class Window_mgr {
public:
    using screen_index = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(screen_index);

private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens{Screen(24, 80, ' ')};  // Error: No ctor for `Screen`
};

/* Part 2, usually Screen.h */
class Screen {
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(screen_index);

public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    using content_type = char;

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, content_type c)
        : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {}

    // Other inline functions are omited.

private:
    pos width = 0;
    pos height = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

/* Part 3, usually Window_mgr.cpp */
void Window_mgr::clear(screen_index i) {
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

The second version (**no error**), which inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31343136/5340808):

```
/* Part 1, usually Window_mgr.h */
class Screen;

class Window_mgr {
public:
    using screen_index = std::vector<Screen>::size_type;
    void clear(screen_index);
    Window_mgr();  // Add ctor declaration

private:
    std::vector<Screen> screens;  // Remove in-class initializer
};

/* Part 2, usually Screen.h */
class Screen {
    friend void Window_mgr::clear(screen_index);

public:
    using pos = std::string::size_type;
    using content_type = char;

    Screen() = default;
    Screen(pos ht, pos wd, content_type c)
        : height(ht), width(wd), contents(ht * wd, c) {}

    // Other inline functions are omited.

private:
    pos width = 0;
    pos height = 0;
    std::string contents;
};

/* Part 3, usually Window_mgr.cpp */
Window_mgr::Window_mgr() : screens{Screen(24, 80, ' ')} {}  // Add ctor definition
// Because `Screen` is already a complete type, we can use its ctor now

void Window_mgr::clear(screen_index i) {
    Screen &s = screens[i];
    s.contents = std::string(s.height * s.width, ' ');
}
```

*Note that I put all 3 parts of code in a single file for convenience, they can also be split into three different files with proper include guards and include header files.*

I understand forward declaration and the include guards, so I'm not asking about them, here are my questions.

1. Is constructor defined outside class `Window_mgr` **the only way** to initialize the data member `screens` if I want to use the class `Screen` directly (not pointer or reference)?

   I think the in-class initializer cannot be used in the first version because `Screen` is incomplete type when its ctor is called.
2. Why an incomplete type (`Screen`) can be used as a parameter to the `vector` template?

Possible similar questions:

- [Member function a friend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31342839/5340808)
- [Friend Class or Friend member function - Forward declaration and Header inclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16551296/5340808)
- [Why aren't my include guards preventing recursive inclusion and multiple symbol definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14909997/5340808)

<sub>I was trying to be clearly but seems a little bit verbose, anyway thanks for reading and helping :)</sub>

Comment: [Minimal incomplete type support for standard containers](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html). Major implementations had already implemented this feature before the paper was written.

Comment: use :: for calling friend function in global scope  ex: ::myfunc()