# Field is not a complete type with forward declaration. Catch 22?

Tags: c++

I need to use a struct defined in A.h as both a parameter to a method as well as a data element to another struct in B.h. (I can't use a pointer to StructA in StructB because the data to which it would point eventually changes, and I need to preserve the original data in a local copy in StructB.)

A.h:

```
struct StructA {
...
}
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h" 
struct StructA;

class B {
  method foo (StructA &structA);
  struct StructB {
     ...
     StructA structA
  }
```

By including A.h in B.h, isn't the declaration of StructA available in B.h? However, the compiler complains that "field structA has incomplete type".

If I don't forward declare StructA, the compiler then complains StructA is not declared in method foo. So, obviously the declaration isn't available in B.h.

I'm missing something fundamental here, but I can't figure it out and it's driving me insane! Please help!

Comment: Can you please post some more code and the actual error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#include "A.h"` does indeed supply `B.h` with the complete type, **however** my guess is that you have a circular include, that's why it doesn't work. Does `A.h` include `B.h` (directly or not)?

Comment: Yes, apparently (indirectly) it is. So the solution is to pull the declaration for StructA and put it in it's own header file?

Comment: It wasn't by itself in A.h and the dependencies were obfuscated by multiple includes. The bottom line is that it was a circular dependency. Although I saw that mentioned elsewhere here with respect to similar problems, I didn't immediately see how it caused the problem. To be honest, it's still not crystal clear to me, so I'll have to review and make sure I understand this and adopt some best practices to avoid this kind of thing in the future.

Comment: @BrianSpisak read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol