# Return class type not recognized in c++

Tags: c++

I have written a class:

**CVerifObj.hpp**:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class VerifObj
{
private:
    cv::Mat m_image;
    PointVector m_plateContour;
    std::string m_imageName;

public:
    VerifObj(const fs::path& imgNameIn);
    ~VerifObj();

    cv::Mat getImage() const;
    std::string getImageName() const;
    PointVector getPlateContour() const;
};

typedef std::vector< VerifObj > VerifObjVector;
```

That has implementation and that is used as a type of another function in another class that includes its header:

**MyCls.hpp**:

```
#pragma once
#include "CVerifObj.hpp"

class MyCls
{
public:
    MyCls();
    ~MyCls();

    static VerifObjVector foo(); // error is here
};
```

The problem I get is that it is not recognized:

```
/home/sop/proj/CMyCls.hpp:52:2: error: ‘VerifObjVector’ does not name a type
```

I have added it in the CMake file too. Why is this happening?

Comment: The error is in CInOut.hpp which you did not show. Show it.

Comment: Please show us the actually faulty code (CInOut.hpp).

Comment: Missing `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Sorry, the error is in `MyCls`

Comment: Probably a problem in the Make file, might as well show us that too

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I have found the problem: I have inserted the function in a class that was not in the right part of the `CMake` file. That is the `VerifObj` class was not added in that part of the `CMake`. In fact this has happened because this was in the testing part. And the `MyCls` was used also in the program; so the error of not recognising the type was not in the test part. I have not added the whole code, because it is very long. I will upvote the answers/comments and comments when I will have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably including `MyCls.hpp` in `CVerifObj.hpp`, directly or indirectly, which leads to a circular include. This can cause issues (undefined types).

Remove circular includes by using forward declarations.

Comment: How can this be avoided? I am using `#pragma once` in each header?

Comment: @sop did you use (or at least google) forward declarations?

Comment: @sop here's a good read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol

Comment: I will do that, now I am using `#pragma once`s

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included the `std::vector` definition:

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: Preferably at the top of `CVerifObj.hpp`.

Comment: Vector is included in `CVerifObj.hpp`