# c++ template function multiple instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write code to convert an `opencv` image to a `QImage`. I want to implement this as a generic function using templates. This is what I have:

```
#include <QImage>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

void setPixel(int j, int i, unsigned char v, QImage & img)
{
    img.setPixel(j, i, qRgb(v, v, v)); 
}        

void setPixel(int j, int i, cv::Vec3b v, QImage & img)
{
    img.setPixel(j, i, qRgb(v[2], v[1], v[0]));
}

template <typename ImageType>
QImage toQImageARGB (const cv::Mat & image)
{
    QImage res(image.cols, image.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    ImageType tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    {   
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {   
            tmp = image.at<ImageType>(i,j);
            setPixel(j, i, tmp, res); 
        }   
    }   
    return res;
}
```

I get the following compile time error

```
CMakeFiles/annotate.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `std::remove_reference<cv::ximgproc::SuperpixelSEEDS*&>::type&& std::move<cv::ximgproc::SuperpixelSEEDS*&>(cv::ximgproc::SuperpixelSEEDS*&)':
.../util.h:8: multiple definition of `setPixel(int, int, unsigned char, QImage&)'
CMakeFiles/annotate.dir/moc_widget.cxx.o:.../build/../util.h:8: first defined here
CMakeFiles/annotate.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> const& cv::Mat::at<cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3> >(int, int) const':
.../util.h:13: multiple definition of `setPixel(int, int, cv::Vec<unsigned char, 3>, QImage&)'
CMakeFiles/annotate.dir/moc_widget.cxx.o:.../build/../util.h:13: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [...] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/annotate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

from my main method.

Is it possible to do this with function templates, and does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems those function definitions (in particular, the two non-template overloads of `setPixel()`) come from a header file that gets included into more than one translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file), thus violating the One Definition Rule.

If you want those functions' definitions to appear in the header file, declare them as `inline`:

```
inline void setPixel(int j, int i, unsigned char v, QImage & img)
{
    img.setPixel(j, i, qRgb(v, v, v)); 
}        

inline void setPixel(int j, int i, cv::Vec3b v, QImage & img)
{
    img.setPixel(j, i, qRgb(v[2], v[1], v[0]));
}
```

Comment: I am wrapping the `util.h` header file in my `CMakeLists.txt`. It also has the `#ifndef` guards. I added the complete compile error.

Comment: @j.dog: First of all, those errors do not come from the compiler, but from the linker. Secondly, header guards do not protect you from multiple inclusions of function definitions from different .cpp files. For more information, see the second question/answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol). To fix the problem, just declare those functions as `inline`, or move their definition to a .cpp file (while leaving the declarations only in the header).