# C++ Templates & Compilation in multiple object files

Tags: c++, class, templates, object, header

After reading about templates, I am confused about their compilation. For example, in a header we define a template as -

```
template<typename T>
class Object {
public:
    Object();
    void hashCode(T& arg){ /* implementation code in header-only. */ }
};
```

We use this template in two source files - SourceI.cpp & SourceII.cpp by including Object.hpp -

SourceI.cpp

```
void doSomething()
{
    Object<int> intHasher;
    intHasher.hashCode();
    // Further code...
}
```

SourceII.cpp

```
void doNothing()
{
     Object<int> notUsedHere;
     notUsedHere.hashCode();
}
```

The compile should generate code for the class instantiation for the "int" type. Where will be the code stored for Object<int> type. Or will the code for Object<int>::hashCode() be inlined in all uses?

If the code is not inlined, then won't symbols clash will linking because they would be present in multiple object files?

**NOTE** - The code is for giving a example and doesn't show any purpose.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile this, both SourceI.cpp and SourceII.cpp will have a copy of Object< int >. This is called code bloating and is one of the drawbacks with using templates.

When you link this, the linker will assume both instantiations of Object< int > are identical and throw away all but one.

Comment: So … there’s no drawback after all (in this case).

Comment: Does that mean the linker must know about C++ templates, after all?

Comment: Also, then pre-compiled headers come in use, right?

Comment: Yes, pre-compiled headers can reduce the compile-time overhead from the template being instantiated in different compilation units.

Comment: @SukantKumar — the linker doesn’t have to know about templates. In general, having two different things with the same name is an error; for some things it’s not, and the linker just picks one. Template instantiations fall in the latter class: duplicates are okay, so just pick one.

Comment: @PeteBecker Clarification of your answer: This works for all type definitions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487918/6307827

Comment: @Andi -- the linker doesn't know anything about types. It deals with names of code and data.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can you explain me why the linker explains about `namespace myproj { int i; }` but does not about `namespace myproj { /*any class, struct, typedef, ...*/ }`, as soon as it is included into several object files?

Comment: @Andi — the first one generates data. The second one doesn’t.