# [Qt]: 'CButton' does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

I have issues with my code. The compiler keeps showing this error for every CButton pointer I created.

```
/home/trafel/ドキュメント/Projects/C++/CCalc/ccalc.h:23: error : 'CButton' does not name a type
     CButton *button_0;
     ^
```

The CButton class extends from QPushButton.
Here is the code from the main header:

```
#ifndef CCALC_H
#define CCALC_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "clabel.h"
#include "cbutton.h"

class CCalc : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CCalc();
    ~CCalc();

public slots:
    void CPush(QString);
    void CAction(QString);

private:
    CButton *button_0;
    CButton *button_1;
    CButton *button_2;
    CButton *button_3;
    CButton *button_4;
    CButton *button_5;
    CButton *button_6;
    CButton *button_7;
    CButton *button_8;
    CButton *button_9;
    CButton *button_equal;
    CButton *button_plus;
    CButton *button_minus;
    CButton *button_multiply;
    CButton *button_divide;
    CButton *button_power;
    CButton *button_root;
    CButton *button_leftParenthesis;
    CButton *button_rightParenthesis;
    CButton *button_return;
    CButton *button_ce;

    CLabel  *label_input;
    CLabel  *label_output;

    QMenu *menu_session;
        QAction *session_new;
        QAction *session_open;
        QAction *session_save;
        QAction *session_quit;
    QMenu *menu_log;
        QAction *log_inspect;
    QMenu *menu_help;
        QAction *help_help;
        QAction *help_about;
};

#endif // CCALC_H
```

And this is from the CButton class header :

```
#ifndef CBUTTON_H
#define CBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include "ccalc.h"

class CButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CButton(QWidget *parent);
    ~CButton();
    QString getValue();
    void setValue(QString string);

private:
    QString value;
};

#endif // CBUTTON_H
```

Did I forget to add something ?

Comment: `ccalc.h` includes `cbutton.h`, but `cbutton.h` includes `ccalc.h`. That's not a good idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol. It looks like you could just remove the include of `ccalc.h` from `cbutton.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short solution:**

In file `"cbutton.h"` replace:

```
#include "ccalc.h"
```

with:

```
class CCalc;
```

or remove that `#include` altogether as it seems you don't use it anyway.

**Explanation:**

Notice you have circular dependencies: in `"ccalc.h"` you need to know what a `CButton` is, and in `"cbutton.h"` you need to know what a `CCalc` is.

This means if `"cbutton.h"` is parsed first, you will hit these lines in this order (only relevant lines shown):

```
1. #define CBUTTON_H      <-- from file "cbutton.h"
2. #include "ccalc.h"     <-- from file "cbutton.h"
3. #include "cbutton.h"   <-- from file "ccalc.h", but as CBUTTON_H is already defined, the content of this file is ignored.
4. CButton *button_0;     <-- from file "ccalc.h", which indeed refers to an undefined class, as we have not reached the line "class CButton" yet.
```

The solution in those cases is, if in `"ccalc.h"` you don't need to know the methods that are in `"cubutton.h"`, but merely to know the class exists, replace that include with a class prototype: `class CButton;`. Same applies to `#include "clabel.h"` and `#include "clabel.h"`.