# C++ compiling program which contain template classes

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

I faced with some compilation issues, here is details:

Lets say I have a declared of some data structure `my_data_struct<typename T>`. The reason I use templates here is I want my data structure to be able to work with any data type (Like `std::stack` or `std::vector` do)

In that case, if I don't know the final types it will be used for, I must define and declare my structure in one file.

Lets say then, I have couple of other libs (divided by `.h` declaration and .cpp definition). Each of them use `my_data_struc`.

Finally, lets say I have `main.cpp` file where "all comes together" with `#include`'s.

How could I get compile my program?

If I will compile my cpp files separately to object files, and will try to link them togather, I will receive `multiple definition of` error, because `my_data_struct` will be defined couple of times...

The only way I realize, is to move definitions of my libs to its declaration (`.h`) files and then just compile the `main.cpp` all at once. But, is it the right way to compile programs like that? Or is there is any better way how to build and compile such stuff?

I didn't find any best practices of how to proceed with it...

Thanks in advice.

UPD:

Well, while creating example, I figured out that the actual issues is caused not by template class, but by non template functions that exists beside the class in the same namespace:

```cpp
//mydatastruct.h
#ifndef MYSTRUCT
#define MYSTRUCT

namespace G{
    template<typename T>
    class my_data_struct{
        public: 
        my_data_struct(){};
        ~my_data_struct(){};
        int do_something(int a){ return a; };
        //...
    };

    int test(int b){ return 2; };
}

#endif
```

```
// a.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "mydatastruct.h"

class A{
    public:
    A();
    ~A();
};

#endif

// a.cpp
#include "a.h"
A::A(){}
A::~A(){}
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "a.h"
int main(){ return 0; }
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -c a.cpp -o a.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ a.o main.o -o main.exe
```

And the actual error is:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `G::test(int)'
a.o:a.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat my question is not about "How to compile template classes", but how to proceed with "multiple definition of" error, when you still need to use template classes! It is not duplicate of linked question!

Comment: I see, reopened. But the question needs a [mcve] instead of a code description.

Comment: I'm tempted to say yes, that is the right way to do it, but I would need a concrete example to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Just updated the question to include reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

Since template definitions can't break [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), if duplicated, they should be accurate duplicates.

> `[C++14: 3.2/6]:` There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements *[..]*

**Edited question**:

Each translation unit goes through separate translation and does not share preprocessor definitions with the others. That's why you end up with multiple definitions in your code. What you need here is a forward declaration. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909997/why-arent-my-include-guards-preventing-recursive-inclusion-and-multiple-symbol) for details.